# Remote to remote copying of files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a function to copy files remote-to-remote using SCP command, paramiko, pexpect, and paramiko-sftp.

I want to make my code efficient; I'm new to Python and I don't know how.

Here's my logic in 3 steps:

1. Find checksum of a file by executing `cksum` command in remote-1.
2. Executing SCP command from my local to copy file remote-1 to remote-2.
3. Again do checksum and compare both to give status.

```
class remote_file_operations():
    """
    Class which supports remote file operations
    """
    def __init__(self, host=None, username=None, password=None, port=22):
        """
        *Method description :* Initialize and setup connection

        :param host: Remote Host
        :type host: str
        :param username: Remote Host Username
        :type username: str
        :param password: Remote Host password
        :type password: str
        :param port: port to connect, default port is 22
        :type port: int
        """
        if host and username and password:
            self.sftp = None
            self.sftp_open = False
            self.client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
            self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            try:
                self.client.connect(host, port=port,
                                username=username, password=password, timeout=10)
            except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
                sys.exit("[Authentication Error] Please check user: '%s' or password" % username)
            except TimeoutError:
                sys.exit("Connection Refused")
            except socket.gaierror:
                sys.exit("Host Name: '%s' not found" % host)

    def _open_sftp_connection(self):
        """
        *Method description :* Opens an SFTP connection if not already open
        """
        if not self.sftp_open:
            self.sftp = self.client.open_sftp()
            self.sftp_open = True
        return self.sftp_open

    @staticmethod
    def file_check_sum(user, host, password, file_paths):
        """
        *Method description :* Give check sum value by cksum command in remote.

        :param user: username :type user: str
        :param host: hostname :type host: str
        :param password: password :type password: str
        :param file_paths: list of file paths :type file_paths: list
        :return check_sum: dict with key as filename and value as checksum :type check_sum: dict
        """
        status = True
        logger.console("Finding checksum ...")
        check_sum = dict()
        rmt_ses = remote_file_operations(host, user, password)
        for file_path in file_paths:
            _, stdout, stderr = rmt_ses.client.exec_command("ls %s" % file_path.replace("\\", ""))
            if b"No such file or directory" not in stderr.read():
                for abs_file_path in stdout:
                    cmd = "cksum %s" % abs_file_path.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
                    (_, stdout, stderr) = rmt_ses.client.exec_command(cmd)
                    sum_line = stdout.read().decode("utf-8").replace(abs_file_path, "")
                    file_name = abs_file_path.split("/")[-1]
                    check_sum[file_name] = sum_line.replace("\n", "").strip()
                    logger.console(check_sum)
            else:
                logger.error("File doesn't exist: %s:%s" % (host, file_path))
                status = False
        rmt_ses.client.close()
        return status, check_sum

    @staticmethod
    def scp_remote_remote(host_1, user_1, password_1, host_2, user_2, password_2, src, dest):
        #pylint: disable=too-many-arguments,try-except-raise,too-many-locals,too-many-branches
        """
        *Method description :* SCP files from one remote to another remote

        :param host_1: Remote host-1  :type host_1: str
        :param user_1: Remote user-1  :type user_1: str
        :param password_1: Remote Host-1 password  :type password_1: str
        :param host_2: Remote host-2  :type host_2: str
        :param user_2: Remote user-2  :type user_2: str
        :param password_2: Remote Host-2 password  :type password_2: str
        :param src: Source dir/file  :type src: str
        :param dest: Destination dir/file  :type dest: str
        :return output: Output generated while scp
        :type output: list
        """
        exp_pwd_2, status, output = None, False, list()
        check, src_check_sum = remote_file_operations.file_check_sum(user_1, host_1, password_1, [src])
        if check:
            command = "scp -r %s@%s:%s %s@%s:%s" % (user_1, host_1, src, user_2, host_2, dest)
            logger.console("Executing: %s" % command)
            try:
                child = pexpect.spawn(command, timeout=COPY_TIMEOUT)
                logger.console("Please wait while copying files from %s to %s ..." % (host_1, host_2))
                exp_pwd_1 = child.expect(["password:", "want to continue connecting"], timeout=10)
                if exp_pwd_1 == 0:
                    child.sendline(password_1)
                elif exp_pwd_1 == 1:
                    child.sendline("yes")
                    child.sendline(password_1)
                exp_pwd_2 = child.expect(["password:", "want to continue connecting"], timeout=10)
                if exp_pwd_2 == 0:
                    child.sendline(password_2)
                elif exp_pwd_2 == 1:
                    child.sendline("yes")
                    child.sendline(password_2)
                child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
                for line in child.before.decode("utf-8").split("\r\n"):
                    for sub_line in line.replace("\r", " ").split("ETA"):
                        logger.console(sub_line)
                    logger.console("\n")
                    output.append(line.replace("\r", " "))
                msg = "scp: %s: " % dest
                if msg + "Permission denied" in output or msg + "No such file or directory" in output:
                    logger.error("Please check the dest path: '%s' exists or have access" % dest)
                elif "scp: /ome/virtuora: No such file or directory" % dest in output:
                    logger.error("Please check the dest path: '%s' exists or have access" % dest)
                else:
                    status = True
            except pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT:
                if "Permission denied" in child.before.decode("utf-8") or "password:"\
                                         in child.before.decode("utf-8"):
                    logger.error("Please check the username or password")
            except pexpect.exceptions.EOF:
                if "ld not resolve hostname" in child.before.decode("utf-8"):
                    logger.error("Please check the Hostnames: '%s', '%s'" % (host_1, host_2))
            if status:
                logger.console(src_check_sum)
                dst_file = [dest + "/" + src.split("/")[-1]]
                status, dst_check_sum = remote_file_operations.file_check_sum(user_2, host_2, password_2, dst_file)
                if status:
                    for src_file, src_check in src_check_sum.items():
                        for dst_file, dst_check in dst_check_sum.items():
                            if src_file == dst_file and src_check == dst_check:
                                logger.console("%s Transfered Successfully" % (src_file))
                                status = True
                            else:
                                logger.console("Something went wrong in file transferring")
        return status, output
```

Answer (score 2):

### Type hints

Move your type documentation:

```
    :type host: str
```

to actual type hints:

```
def __init__(self, host: Optional[str]=None, username: Optional[str]=None, password: Optional[str]=None, port: int=22):
```

### String interpolation

```
            sys.exit("Host Name: '%s' not found" % host)
```

can be

```
            sys.exit(f"Host Name: '{host}' not found")
```

### Object closure

```
    rmt_ses = remote_file_operations(host, user, password)
    # ...
    rmt_ses.client.close()
```

So a few things. `remote_file_operations` should be `RemoteFileOperations` since it's a class. Also, it's not clear to me that this `file_check_sum` method should be a `static` on the class - it makes just as much sense for it to be a function in global scope.

Also, reaching into the object to `client.close()` is poor coupling; the class should be turned into a context manager whose `__exit__` calls its `client.close()`. Then, `file_check_sum` would use `RemoteFileOperations` in a `with`.